# The Most Simplest jQuery Upload Method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, upload

I am looking for the simplest jQuery Upload Method or plugin. So simple like:

```
$("input[type=file]").uploadfile("phpfilename.php");
```

Can anyone help me with this??

Comment: This is not how [so] operates. Please read the [ask] section of the [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote one, here's [github project](https://github.com/iamfaiz/jQuery-Upload-Function).

### Simple Example:

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function() {
    $(this).ajaxUpload({
        url: "serverside.php",
        fileName: "file",
        callback: function(responseFromServerSide) {
            console.log(responseFromServerSide);
        }
    });
});
```

For more examples see the examples folder in the project.